# Logstash: Is it possible to take file input from remote host

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to feed a log file to logstash. But the file is on a remote host. Is there a way to make logstash consume this file? Then, I will forward the events to an elasticsearch instance running on the same machine as logstash.

Conversely, is it possible to run logstash on one machine but send output to elasticsearch running on another machine?

Comment: For this you can use https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat

Comment: thanks, but is filebeats free?

Comment: As far as I know beats is open and free: https://github.com/elastic/beats

Comment: thanks, i was looking at the documentation but i could not find the syntax for pointing to a remote file. ideally, i do not want to run logstash or filebeats on the machine where my log file is

Comment: You can use rsync to sync your files to a location on your logstash deployment and watch that location with a regular file input